# Confusion about the radius of convergence and the ratio test

Tags: real-analysis

My textbook is a bit unclear on what exactly the radius of convergence is.

It states that we define the radius of convergence of $\Sigma a_nx^n$ to be given by:

$$
R :=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $\rho=+\infty$}\\
1/\rho &\text{if $0<\rho<+\infty$}\\
+\infty &\text{if $\rho=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

And then on the next page it says "the radius of convergence of the series $\Sigma a_nx^n$ is also given by":
$$
\lim{\lvert{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}}\rvert}
$$

I'm confused about the notation.  Do they mean that R = $\lim{\lvert{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}}\rvert}$ ? Or that  $\rho = \lim{\lvert{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}}\rvert}$?

Can I just use the ratio test to solve for the radius of convergence like normal?  How does $\rho$ come into play for the ratio test?  I guess I'm confused because of all the reciprocity and I want to make sure I have things straight.

For example:

$\sum \frac{x^n}{4^nlnn}$

If I apply the ratio test:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\lvert{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}}\rvert} < 1$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\lvert{\frac{x^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}ln(n+1)}\frac{4^{n}ln(n)}{x^{n}}}\rvert} < 1$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}{{\frac{lnn}{4ln(n+1)}}\lvert x\rvert} < 1$

$\frac{1}{4}\lvert x\rvert < 1$

$\lvert x\rvert < 4$

So $R=4$, correct?  What is $\rho$ in this scenario?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root formula with lim sup in the computation of $\rho$ is always correct, this is the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem.

The ratio formula is only correct if the limit exists. If it does not exist, the lim sup and lim inf give upper and lower bounds on the radius of convergence.

---

As for the example, the convergence analysis you did is correct, but it is using the criterion for number series, putting $x$ as a parameter. Be careful of how you distribute the letters, here one could use
$$
a_n=c_n\,x^n=\frac{x^n}{4^n\ln n},\text{ i.e., }c_n=\frac{1}{4^n\ln n}.
$$
In power series terms, $\rho=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\frac14$ and also $\rho=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|=\frac14$, since this limit exists. So $R=\rho^{-1}=4$.

Comment: That doesn't quite clarify things for me.  What is $\rho$ in the example I put above?  Not talking about Cauchy-Hadamard theorem here, just ratio test.  Thanks.

Comment: @user114014: I added my remarks to the answer.